# html div element on click getting appened

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a vertical menu where there are 5 items webdesign, mobile app etc., as shown below and when clicked on that it shows the respective href attribute.

```
<div class="col-md-3">  
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">  
            <li class="active">  
            <a href="#web" onclick="webdesDiv()">Web Design and Development</a>   </li>     
            <li><a href="#mob" onclick="mobileDiv()">Mobile Applicaiton Development</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#ecom" onclick="ecommDiv()">eCommerce Solutions </a></li>   
            <li><a href="#soft" onclick="softDiv()">Software development</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#supp" onclick="supportDiv()">Support & Maintenance</a></li>   
        </ul>  
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="webdesc">  
        <h4>This is how the webdesign  page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>

    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="mobdesc">  
        <h4>This is how the mobile app section page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>      
    </div>
```

The problem is, when i click on  Mobile application development, respective description is coming correctly, where as when i click on other option ex: ecommerce solutions, result is getting appended in same page.  I need only that particular description rather than getting result appended. Kindly suggest fixes in my code .

My javascript code :

```
<script>
        function mobileDiv() 
        {
        document.getElementById('mobdesc').style.display = "block";
        }
        function webdesDiv() 
        {
        document.getElementById('webdesc').style.display = "block";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Where you are calling functions `mobileDiv()` and `webdesDiv()` ?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya : when i click on Web Design and Development list element onclick function for webdesDiv() wil be called same is the case for mobileDiv(), it will be invoked when i click on Mobile App development list element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Way :

```
<script>
    function mobileDiv() 
    {
        document.getElementById('mobdesc').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('webdesc').style.display = "none";
    }
    function webdesDiv() 
    {
        document.getElementById('webdesc').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('mobdesc').style.display = "none";
    }
 </script>
```

Make only one div to `display:block` and rest of other `display:none`

Comment: Very inefficient to have a function per click and also the click event should be cancelled.

Comment: Hi Actually I'm looking out for responsive web design. And when i click on web design and development description section it should come right below to it where as now it is coming after all the list elements. Would be great if you rectify this too.  thanks in advance

Comment: For that put respective `div` after respective `li` elements. Like : `<li class="active"><a href="#web" onclick="webdesDiv()">Web Design and Development</a>
            <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="webdesc">  
        <h4>This is how the webdesign  page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>
    </div>  </li>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add display:none for the blocks other than the one you clicked.

Your script should look something like this:

```js
function mobileDiv() 
        {
          document.getElementById('mobdesc').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('webdesc').style.display = "none";
        }
        function webdesDiv() 
        {
          document.getElementById('webdesc').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('mobdesc').style.display = "none"
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">  
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">  
            <li class="active">  
            <a href="#web" onclick="webdesDiv()">Web Design and Development</a>   </li>     
            <li><a href="#mob" onclick="mobileDiv()">Mobile Applicaiton Development</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#ecom" onclick="ecommDiv()">eCommerce Solutions </a></li>   
            <li><a href="#soft" onclick="softDiv()">Software development</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#supp" onclick="supportDiv()">Support & Maintenance</a></li>   
        </ul>  
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="webdesc">  
        <h4>This is how the webdesign  page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>

    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="mobdesc">  
        <h4>This is how the mobile app section page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>      
    </div>
```

Apply display:none to the blocks other than the one which is clicked.

**A small suggestion:** Since it looks like you're using bootstrap, use bootstrap navigation component - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav.

Comment: Thank you somuch Dilip for your time and assistance it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the non-active div

If I were to code this in plain JS, I would not use hashes that go nowhere but make them useful. 
The following unobtrusively adds the event handlers to each link and use their hash to show/hide the repective div and to activate/deactivate the parent LI

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li a"); // get all nav links
  for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) { // loop over them
    navLinks[i].onclick = function() { // assign click handlers
      var activeLink = document.querySelector(".nav > li.active > a"),
        activeDivId = activeLink.hash.substring(1),
        activeLI = activeLink.parentNode;
      document.getElementById(activeDivId).style.display = "none"; // hide active div
      activeLI.className = ""; // make LI non-active
      activeDivId = this.hash.substring(1); // find new div ID 
      document.getElementById(activeDivId).style.display = "block"; // show it
      this.parentNode.className = "active"; // activate the LI
      return false; // cancel the click
    }
  }
  document.querySelector(".nav > li.active > a").click(); // show active link
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#webdesc">Web Design and Development</a>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="webdesc">
        <h4>This is how the webdesign  page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#mobdesc">Mobile Application Development</a>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="display:none;" id="mobdesc">
        <h4>This is how the mobile app section page looks like</h4>
        <p>Secure and highly interactive eCommerce storefront that is designed to leverage your product sales is developed using the latest coding techniques in the industry.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery if needed

```
$(function() {
  var $navLinks = $(".nav li a"); // get all nav links
  $navLinks.each(function() { // loop over them
    $(this).on("click", function(e) { // assign click handlers
      e.preventDefault();
      var $activeLink = $(".nav > li.active > a"),
          $activeLI = $activeLink.parent();
      $($activeLink.prop("hash")).hide(); // hide active div
      $activeLI.removeClass("active"); // make LI non-active
      $(this.hash).show(); // show it
      $(this).parent().addClass("active"); // activate the LI
    });
  });
  $(".nav > li.active > a").click(); // show active link
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your time and assistance.  Yes sir, im looking out for responsive web design.  And when i click on web design and development description section should come right below to it where as now it is coming after all the list elements.  Would be great if you rectify this.  Thanks again sir in advance

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. OK if i check it in mobile and if i click on Web design and development(list element) description should come below the same and after that Mobile application development(another list element) should follow.  where as now When i click on web design and development, explanation is coming after the complete nav bar.  Hope this time i m some what clear atleast

Comment: See update. I moved the divs under their respective LI

Comment: Thanks for a providing me a great learning experience.  Thanks again.